# LinkedIn API - Can't create access tokens to pull data from Advertising API using Python

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am trying to use Python to extract data directly from the Advertising API in LinkedIn.

When I run this code with my Client ID and Client Secret entered in, I get "Error 401: This application is not allowed to create application tokens".

To my understanding the error relates to how I am trying to authenticate my credentials to access the data. Do you know if its an issue with my code, or its something that LinkedIn needs to enable on their end?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

CLIENT_ID = 'My Client ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'My Client Secret'
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'
API_BASE_URL = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/'
ENDPOINT = 'adAccountsV2'

def get_access_token():
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET
    }
    response = requests.post(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, data=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
        return access_token
    else:
        print(f"Failed to get access token. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(f"Response content: {response.text}")
        return None

def make_api_request(endpoint, access_token):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
    }
    response = requests.get(API_BASE_URL + endpoint, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

def extract_data(access_token):
    endpoint = 'adAccountsV2'
    data = make_api_request(endpoint, access_token)
    return data

def save_to_csv(data, file_path):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    access_token = get_access_token()
    if access_token:
        extracted_data = extract_data(access_token)
        save_to_csv(extracted_data, 'output.csv')
    else:
        print("Failed")
```